# « Être une évocation de qqch./être pour rappeler à qqn. qqch./ne faire que rappeler à la mém. de qqn. qqch./s'agir que de l'évocation de qqch. » ?

Tags: usage, choix-de-mot, expressions-idiomatiques, reformulation

> C’était seulement une évocation du comportement imprudent que ta mère a déjà eu par le passé, dont tu n’étais pas fière et que tu condamnais vivement. Le moins que l’on puisse dire est qu’en l’occurrence tu ne prêches pas d’exemple.

> C’était juste pour te rappeler [le souvenir] que ta mère s’est déjà comportée par le passé comme tu as agi aujourd’hui et que tu n’étais pas fière d’elle au point de la blâmer violemment. Le moins que l’on puisse dire est qu’en l’occurrence tu ne prêches pas d’exemple.

> Je ne faisais que rappeler à ta mémoire que ta mère s’est déjà comportée ainsi par le passé et qu’elle avait essuyé une critique acerbe de ta part. Le moins que l’on puisse dire est qu’en l’occurrence tu ne prêches pas d’exemple.

> Il ne s’agit que de l’évocation de souvenirs que tu devrais avoir de ta mère. Tu étais peu fière de son comportement imprudent d’alors et tu le condamnais vivement. Le moins que l’on puisse dire est que tu ne prêches pas d’exemple en l’occurrence.

Je m’attends à une formulation qui se dit aisément à l’oral et qui respecte dans une certaine mesure (quelques libertés sont autorisées) le bon usage. En d’autres de mots je veux savoir ce que vous auriez vous-même dit spontanément dans la situation à laquelle je fais allusion dans la phrase.

Comment: L'expression *prêcher d'exemple* est oubliée en France. Elle y est remplacée par  *prêcher par l'exemple*.

Comment: Il n'est pas possible d'écrire « te rappeler  le souvenir que ta mère s’est déjà… » ;  si une explication vous intéresse poser la question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toutes ces phrases renferment au moins une idée qui n'est  dans aucune des autres. En conséquence, je suppose que ce qu'on demande est une reformulation de chacune d'entre elles.

**I**

> C’était seulement une évocation du comportement imprudent que ta mère a déjà eu par le passé, dont tu n’étais pas fière et que tu condamnais vivement. Le moins que l’on puisse dire c'est qu'à en juger par ta façon d'agir tu ne prêches pas par l’exemple.

*C’était seulement un rappel des imprudences auxquelles ta mère s'est laissée aller par le passé ;  tu n’en étais pas fière et  tu lui reprochais vivement son manque de bon sens. Le moins que l’on puisse dire c'est qu'à en juger par ta façon d'agir tu ne prêches pas par l’exemple.*

**II**

> C’était juste pour te rappeler que ta mère s’est déjà comportée par le passé comme tu as agi aujourd’hui et que tu n’étais pas fière d’elle au point de la blâmer violemment. Le moins que l’on puisse dire c'est qu'à en juger par ta façon d'agir tu ne prêches pas par l’exemple.

*C’était juste pour te rappeler qu'il est arrivé à ta mère  par le passé de se comporter comme tu l’as fait aujourd’hui et que tu étais si peu  fière d’elle que tu l'en blâmais violemment. Le moins que l’on puisse dire c'est qu'à en juger par ta façon d'agir tu ne prêches pas par l’exemple.*

**III**

> Je ne faisais que rappeler à ta mémoire que ta mère s’est déjà comportée ainsi par le passé et qu’elle avait essuyé une critique acerbe de ta part. Le moins que l’on puisse dire est qu’en l’occurrence tu ne prêches pas d’exemple.

*Je ne faisais que te remettre en  mémoire un comportement de ta mère que tu as eu l'occasion  de lui reprocher par une critique sans pitié, mais tu agis comme elle. Le moins que l’on puisse dire c'est qu'à en juger par ta façon d'agir tu ne prêches pas par l’exemple.*

**IV**

> Il ne s’agit que de l’évocation de souvenirs que tu devrais avoir de ta mère. Tu étais peu fière de son comportement imprudent d’alors et tu le condamnais vivement. Le moins que l’on puisse dire est que tu ne prêches pas d’exemple en l’occurrence.

*Je ne fais que te parler de souvenirs  de ta mère, et tu ne les a pas oubliés. Tu étais peu fière de son comportement imprudent dans ce temps-là et tu le critiquais vivement. Le moins que l’on puisse dire c'est qu'à en juger par ta façon d'agir tu ne prêches pas par l’exemple.*

Comment: *Il n'y a pas une seule de ces phrases qui n'exprime des idées qui ne soit différente**s** de celle exprimée dans les autres* gagnerait à être simplifié en : *Ces quatre phrases expriment la même idée*.

Comment: @jlliagre J'ai pensée à cette négation double, qui n'en est pas vraiment une parce que le second « n' » est explétif, mais il me semblait en fin de compte que l'utiliser permettait une construction plus forte (emphase) au moyen de la tournure « Il n'y a pas une seule » ; de toute façon la correspondance n'est pas « Ces quatre phrases expriment la même idée » ; le sens est « dans toutes il y a au moins une idée que l'on ne trouve pas dans les autres ». Néanmoins, je vois une autre erreur (celles exprimées), alors je vais essayer de changer ça.

Comment: Ah oui, le singulier impliquait le contraire de ce tu voulais dire. Ta nouvelle phrase est claire mais je remplacerais *[...] qui n'est pas dans toutes les autres* par *{...] que l'on ne retrouve pas dans les autres*.